# Hosting WCF service created in VS2010 on IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis

I have been through tons of threads and am unable to find the correct answer for my question.  I have created a very simple WCF service on my development machine using visual studio 2010.  The service works correctly when using VS to host it.  I have even had success creating a small c# application to consume this service.  However I now need to move this service to IIS on  my work's development server.  I have tried following several guides online but nothing has worked so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'Nothing has worked' is extremely generic.  Try giving more details such as exception messages.

Comment: can you generate a  WSDL if you browse to the service? Please give more info on what you have tried.

Comment: When on visual studio I can run the service and enter in test values and everything returns and runs okay.  When deploying to the development service I create a website and application following the guide at this location: http://nikpatel.net/2012/03/07/step-by-step-building-and-consuming-custom-wcf-services-hosted-in-iis-using-wcf-application-approach/.  When using this guide the website does not work.  A page not found message comes up whenever navigating to the url.

Comment: Can you post your web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are able to execute your wcf service using WCFTestClient successfully and not on IIS

that means problem is in endpoint configuration. I suggest have a look once again endpoint suggestions.

Comment: You were correct.  I had an error in the endpoint configuration.  Thank you very much for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Using Web Deploy to publish from Visual Studio to a remote web server requires additional installation of Web Deploy on the server http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

Visual Studio generates an output log during the web deploy publish  that may have additional information on why it is failing. Sometimes there are permission issues to work through as well http://blogs.iis.net/krolson/archive/2009/11/04/using-iis-manager-accounts-for-web-deployment-tool-msdeploy-delegation.aspx

You can also generate a Web Deploy Package with Visual Studio and manually deploy it to the server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx